# MySQL Duplicate error with ALTER IGNORE TABLE

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mysql-error-1062

I have a table in my MySQL with duplicates. I try to delete the duplicates and keep one entry. I don't have a primary key

I can finde the duplicates by:

```
select user_id, server_id, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from user_server
group by user_id, server_id
having NumDuplicates > 1
```

But can't delete them with:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `user_server`  
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`user_id`, `server_id`);
```

Even SET foreign_key_checks = 0; is not working. 
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '142-20' for key 'user_id_3'

MySQL version: 5.5.18
Engine: InnoDB

Is there an other way?

Comment: Do you want to delete identically rows or do they have columns with different values?

Comment: just identically rows, but keep one of the duplicates

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, can anyone explain why ALTER IGNORE TABLE doesn't remove the duplicates in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to copy the structure of the table, add the unique index to the new table and then do:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table
```

---

To delete the duplicates (except one of each) without creating a temp table, you can do that:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_server` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

DELETE us2 FROM user_server us1
 JOIN user_server us2 USING (user_id, server_id)
 WHERE us1.id < us2.id;

ALTER TABLE `user_server` DROP `id`;
```

Comment: I'm searching for a way without copy the table and rename it again. Only if everything else don't work.

Answer (score 13):

It's because you use INNO DB,

A simple trick :

```
set session old_alter_table=1;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `user_server`  
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`user_id`, `server_id`);
set session old_alter_table=0;
```

This do the job

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, which keeps any indexes that were on the user_server is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_user_server LIKE user_server;
ALTER TABLE new_user_server ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`user_id`, `server_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_user_server SELECT * FROM user_server;
DROP TABLE user_server;
RENAME TABLE new_user_server TO user_server;
```